# How to select or unselect all checkboxes in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, selectall, unselect

I have several collapsible check-boxes, and am trying to check/uncheck all the boxes within that section.

**HTML**

Currently when I click on the main checkbox, it simply opens and closes the collapsible dialog.

```
<li data-role="collapsible" id="educationlayers">
            <h3>
                <input type="checkbox" name="education" id="education" class="layers"/>
                <label for="education">Education</label>
            </h3>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="daycare" class="layers"/>
                <label for="daycare">Day Care</label>
                <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="elementary" class="layers"/>
                <label for="elementary">Elementary</label>
                <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="intermediate" class="layers"/>
                <label for="highschool">High School</label>
                <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="postsecondary" class="layers"/>
                <label for="postsecondary">Post Secondary School</label>
            </fieldset>
         </li> 
         <li data-role="collapsible" id="emergencylayers">
               <h3>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="emergency" id="emergency" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="emergency">Emergency</label>
                </h3>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="emergency" id="ambulance" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="ambulance">Ambulance Station</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="emergency" id="fire" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="fire">Fire Station</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="emergency" id="hospital" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="hospital">Hospital</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="emergency" id="police" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="police">Police</label>
                </fieldset>
          </li>
          <li data-role="collapsible" id="facilitieslayers">
                 <h3>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="facilities" id="facilities" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="facilities">Facilities</label>
                </h3>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="facilities" id="commerce" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="commerce">Chamber of Commerce</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="facilities" id="cityfacility" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="cityfacility">City Facility</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="facilities" id="cityhall" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="cityhall">City Hall</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="facilities" id="govfacility" class="layers"/>
                    <label for="govfacility">Government Facility</label>
                </fieldset>
          </li>
```

**JQuery**

JQuery code that doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    fixContentHeight();
    $('#education').click(function() {
        $("INPUT[name='education']").attr('checked', $('#education').is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

Any tips would be helpful!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Refer my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11331931/500725)**

Comment: I got your problem and i have updated my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11331931/500725)** and look at my live demo to see working version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't about what this function (`fixContentHeight();`) is doing.

Do this way, it works as expected.

```
//fixContentHeight();
$('#education').click(function() {
    $("INPUT[name='education']")
        .attr({
            checked: $('#education').is(':checked')
        });
});​
```

Follow the same fashion for other checkbox sections.

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/XcsPP/)**

### UPDATED:

Refer this same piece of code which I have done some modifications to works for all checkbox sections,

```
//fixContentHeight();
$('h3 input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $("INPUT[name='"+this.name+"']")
        .attr({
            checked: $(this).is(':checked')
        });
});​
```

### HTML:

Actually on your HTML `<UL>` tag is missing.

```
<ul>
    <li data-role="collapsible" id="educationlayers">
        <h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="education" id="education" class="layers"/>
            <label for="education">Education</label>
        </h3>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="daycare" class="layers"/>
            <label for="daycare">Day Care</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="elementary" class="layers"/>
            <label for="elementary">Elementary</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="intermediate" class="layers"/>
            <label for="highschool">High School</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="education" id="postsecondary" class="layers"/>
            <label for="postsecondary">Post Secondary School</label>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" id="emergencylayers">
        <h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="emergency" id="emergency" class="layers"/>
            <label for="emergency">Emergency</label>
        </h3>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="emergency" id="ambulance" class="layers"/>
            <label for="ambulance">Ambulance Station</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="emergency" id="fire" class="layers"/>
            <label for="fire">Fire Station</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="emergency" id="hospital" class="layers"/>
            <label for="hospital">Hospital</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="emergency" id="police" class="layers"/>
            <label for="police">Police</label>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
    <li data-role="collapsible" id="facilitieslayers">
        <h3>
            <input type="checkbox" name="facilities" id="facilities" class="layers"/>
            <label for="facilities">Facilities</label>
        </h3>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="facilities" id="commerce" class="layers"/>
            <label for="commerce">Chamber of Commerce</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="facilities" id="cityfacility" class="layers"/>
            <label for="cityfacility">City Facility</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="facilities" id="cityhall" class="layers"/>
            <label for="cityhall">City Hall</label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="facilities" id="govfacility" class="layers"/>
            <label for="govfacility">Government Facility</label>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/XcsPP/1/)**

## UPDATED 2:

I have gone through your code and modified it. Finally I got your issue with the checkboxes.

You need to refresh the `checkboxradio`, to get updated with checked value of all checkboxes.

You need to use:-

```
$("input[name='"+this.name+"']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

**JS:**

```
$('h3 input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $("input[name='"+this.name+"']")
        .attr({
            checked: $(this).is(':checked')
        });
    $("input[name='"+this.name+"']").checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/XcjR3/7/)**

Comment: The fixContentHeight(); is because I'm working with JQuery-Mobile, so I need it for the mobile devices.
But, your code didn't work either

Comment: @raster: Have you referred my live demo 2?

Comment: Unfortunately, placing ul tags and the updated checkbox code breaks my entire project

Comment: @raster: I have updated the answer. Refer LIVE DEMO 3. I got your problem, you need to refresh the checkboxes when ever you click on main section.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the click event from bubbling up to your `<li>`  which is collapsible.

```
$('h3 input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e) {
    $("INPUT[name='"+this.name+"']")
        .attr({
            checked: $(this).is(':checked')
        });
    e.stopPropagation();  //<--stops the click from bubbling up.
});​
```

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

edit: reading more about the collapsible, in theory only click the `header` should be collapsing the `li`.   check to make sure your `<h3>` tags are all closed properly and there isn't any stray elements missing closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('h3 input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
        var selected = $(this).attr('id');
        $("INPUT[name="+selected +"]").attr({checked: $(this).is(':checked')});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/p584k/6/

Comment: The example was really helpful, but it didn't seem to help. When i select the 'Education' checkbox it still opens and closes the collapsible dialog

Comment: Can you jsfiddle your entire area including the plugin

Comment: I have placed my entire hmtl and jquery-mobile code in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/XcjR3/8/
It would be amazing if you could take a quick look and make sure I'm not overlooking anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think,you want this:

```
$('h3 :checkbox').change(function() {
    //'$(this).parent().next()' is appropriate 'fieldset' element
    $(this).parent().next().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

This should work for all 3 ` **education**, **emergency**, **facilities** .

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Emq4d/)

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to help. When i select the 'Education' check-box it still opens and closes the collapsible dialog

Comment: @raster See my code again.I have changed it,and added a *demo*.

Comment: @raster 'How to select or unselect all checkboxes in JQuery Mobile?' is your question's title,and I have provided a solution to that, and provided demo either.

Comment: Sorry, I saw the demo, and understand that it works, but when I try to place it into my project, it doesn't change anything. Thank you for your help though, I'm going to keep fiddling with what you've given me

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question is old but for those looking for a jQuery 2.x and jQuery Mobile 1.4.3 example try this:

---

**HTML :**

---

```
<div data-role="page" id="chk">
    <div data-role="header"> <a href="#sc" data-icon="home">CSA</a>
         <h1>katalin_2003</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-c">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <input type="button" id="button1" data-theme="b" value="check all" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <input type="button" id="button2" data-theme="b" value="uncheck all" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <input type="button" id="button3" data-theme="b" value="check grp1" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d">
                <input type="button" id="button4" data-theme="b" value="check grp2" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-content-theme="a">
    <h4>grp1</h4>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" grp="1" name="checkboxArr1[]" id="checkbox-v-1a" data-theme="b" />
            <label for="checkbox-v-1a">One</label>
            <input type="checkbox" grp="1" name="checkboxArr1[]" id="checkbox-v-1b" data-theme="b" />
            <label for="checkbox-v-1b">Two</label>
            <input type="checkbox" grp="1" name="checkboxArr1[]" id="checkbox-v-1c" data-theme="b" />
            <label for="checkbox-v-1c">Three</label>
        </fieldset>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
    <h4>grp2</h4>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" grp="2" name="checkboxArr2[]" id="checkbox-v-2a" data-theme="a" />
            <label for="checkbox-v-2a">One</label>
            <input type="checkbox" grp="2" name="checkboxArr2[]" id="checkbox-v-2b" data-theme="a" />
            <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
            <input type="checkbox" grp="2" name="checkboxArr2[]" id="checkbox-v-2c" data-theme="a" />
            <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
        </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

**JS**

---

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(e) {
    $('#button1').on( "click", function() {
        $('#chk input[type=checkbox][grp=1], #chk input[type=checkbox][grp=2]').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
        console.log('ALL checked');
    });
    $('#button2').on( "click", function() {
        $('#chk input[type=checkbox][grp=1], #chk input[type=checkbox][grp=2]').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
        console.log('ALL UNchecked');   
    });
    $('#button3').on( "click", function() {
        $('#chk input[type=checkbox][grp=1]').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
        $('#chk input[type=checkbox][grp=2]').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
        console.log('grp1 checked');    
    });
    $('#button4').on( "click", function() {
        $('#chk input[type=checkbox][grp=2]').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
        $('#chk input[type=checkbox][grp=1]').prop('checked', false).checkboxradio('refresh');
        console.log('grp2 checked');    
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/katalin_2003/uHcQL/)**

Answer (score 0):

All the answers on Stack Overflow don't work for me.

The following is the solution I finally found:

You can try `$("#radioLabel1").trigger("click");`
where `radioLabel1` is the id of the radio's label.

My working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('pagecreate', function(evt) {     
$('#checkall_home').click(function(evt) {   //checkall_home is the id of the checkall button
    if(evt.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {
        //alert('Clicked');
        if ($("#checkall_home").html()=="Check All"){
            //alert("Checking All");
            $("#checkall_home").html("Uncheck All");
            $("input.cbxGroupHome").prop("checked", false);  //first deselect all of the checkboxes with class name "cbxGroupHome", then simulate clicking on all the labels associated with the checkboxes (i.e. has a for="#id" attribute), which are denoted by the class name "lb_cb_home"
            $(".lb_cb_home").trigger("click");
        }else{
           // alert("unchecking all");
            $("#checkall_home").html("Check All");
            $("input.cbxGroupHome").prop("checked", true);//.checkboxradio("refresh");
            $(".lb_cb_home").trigger("click");
        }
        evt.handled = true;
    }
});
});
</script>


<form method="get" action="">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup"><!--Because checkboxes use the label element for the text displayed next to the checkbox form element, we recommend wrapping the checkbox in a fieldset element that has a legend which acts as the title for the question.
   Add the data-role="controlgroup" attribute to the fieldset so it can be styled in a parallel way as text inputs, selects or other form elements.-->
    <!-- <legend><h4>Ingredients</h4>`</legend>-->

 <input id="cb2" type="checkbox" class="cbxGroupHome"/> 
<label class="lb_cb_home" for="cb2">1 cup vegetable oil</label>

<input id="cb3" type="checkbox" class="cbxGroupHome"/>
<label class="lb_cb_home" for="cb3">13 pounds fresh green beans, trimmed</label>

<input id="cb4" type="checkbox" class="cbxGroupHome"/> 
<label class="lb_cb_home" for="cb4">5 tablespoons minced garlic</label>

<input id="cb5" type="checkbox" class="cbxGroupHome"> 
<label class="lb_cb_home" for="cb5">5 tablespoons minced fresh ginger root</label>
</fieldset>
</form>
```