# Check/Uncheck all checkboxes in jquery mobile fails

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquerymobile page with two buttons. One two check all checkboxes and one to uncheck all checkboxes. **First time I click on `check all` it works, but after unchecking it doesn't works anymore.**

Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="selecttest">

    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#sc" data-icon="home">SSC</a>
        <h1>...</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><button onclick="$('#selecttest input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked','checked').checkboxradio('refresh');" data-theme="b">check all</button></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button onclick="$('#selecttest input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked').checkboxradio('refresh');" data-theme="b">uncheck all</button></div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2a" id="checkbox-v-2a">
            <label for="checkbox-v-2a">One</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2b" id="checkbox-v-2b">
            <label for="checkbox-v-2b">Two</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-v-2c" id="checkbox-v-2c">
            <label for="checkbox-v-2c">Three</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div><!-- /page -->
```

I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 with jQuerymobile 1.3

I've already taken a look at [How to select or unselect all checkboxes in JQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331812/how-to-select-or-unselect-all-checkboxes-in-jquery-mobile) but it hasn't helped me.

Comment: @MattBusche In the onclick parameter?

Comment: For starters I would highly recommend not using inline JavaScript

Comment: You are right, for starters...

Comment: you should be using `.prop` to change checked status, not `.attr`

Comment: It seems to work for me, here's a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ehujuf/1/edit). I think there is something else wrong with your code.

Comment: @Jack That's interesting, it works with jQuery 1.6.4 (what your are using in your jsBin) but not with jQuery 1.9.1 (I've tried it out).

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, you should post this as an answer. It solved my question!

Comment: I'm with @KevinB and @Jack - you should be using `.prop` but the code runs on my local machine just fine

Comment: @wumm I actually just selected *latest JQM* in the jsBin and it added jQuery 1.6.4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery 1.9 re-instated the changes that were done to .attr in 1.6 and removed in 1.6.1. This means that the `.attr` vs `.prop` is now back to being strict. If you need to manipulate properties, use `.prop`, else, use `.attr`. It's very rare that you actually would want to work with the attribute.

For checked state of a checkbox, you should be using `.prop("checked",true)` or `.prop("checked",false)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('h3 :checkbox').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

var tasiyici = "form1";

  if($(this).prop("checked")== true)
  {
  tumunuSec(tasiyici,true);
  }else{
  tumunuSec(tasiyici,false); 
  }


});

$('#form1 input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 var truesayisi = $("#form1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").size();
 var checksayisi = $("#form1 input[type=checkbox]").size();
  if(truesayisi == checksayisi)
  {
   $('h3 :checkbox').prop("checked",true);
  } 
  if(truesayisi < checksayisi)
  {
   $('h3 :checkbox').prop("checked",false);
  }
});

function tumunuSec(FormAdi, cvalue){
  var truesayisi = 0;
    $.each($("#"+FormAdi+" input[type=checkbox]"), function(){
        $(this).prop("checked",cvalue).checkboxradio("refresh");
  truesayisi++;

    });  


}
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>


<div class="cont-a" style="min-width:280px !important; width:90% !important; max-width:380px !important;">
 <h3  style="padding:8px; margin:0px !important; background:#222; border-radius:4px; text-align:center;">
 <input type="checkbox" name="secici" id="secici" style="margin:0px;" class="tipso" title="Select All"><p>TOPLU İŞLEM</p></h3>
 <form action="kontrol.php" method="post" data-ajax="false" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">
  <fieldset class="ui-field-contain" data-role="controlgroup" id="form1" data-filter="true" STYLE="width:100%; border:0px solid #ffcc00">
   <input type="checkbox" name="menuler[]" value="1" id="1">
   <label for="1">Menü 1</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="menuler[]" value="2" id="2">
   <label for="2">Menü 2</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="menuler[]" value="3" id="3">
   <label for="3">Menü 3</label>

  </fieldset>
    <div class="no-results" >Kayıt bulunamadı.</div> 
  <input type="submit" value="yolla" />
 </form>
</div>
```